# jQuery compression leads to errors

Tags: jquery, compression

could someone please explain when I have a jquery script which runs fine with no errors and then compress and upload it then returns errors?

Much appreciated.

EDIT The only error im getting using jsLint is:

Error:

Implied global: $ 3,25,27,28,31,32,34,35,36,38,45,46,47,49,50,61,63,64,65,67,71,75,79,83,87,91,94,95,96,98,101,102,103,111,113,114,115,121,123,124,125,127,130,131,132,142,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,171,173,174,175,177,180,181,182,192,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,214,216,217,218,220,223,224,225,234,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260, window 7, alert 56,106,137,187,230, document 234

which is cause its in jQuery im guessing

Comment: You can tweak jslint to disable various checks that only affects code style and not errors.

Access to variables that is not declared using var are implied global. You can specify external global variables using the 
/*global ... */ comment directive.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you are missing the statement terminator `;` at some line(s), for example following code would run fine even if i don't specify that:

```
$(....).click(function(){
  .....
}) <-- // no `;` char here
```

Or even this:

```
alert('hello') <-- // no `;` char here
```

But when you compress it, and you have forgot to place that character somewhere, you will receive the errors.

Make sure this is not the case in your script other than any possible issue.

Comment: I have checked that ( ran into that problem before ) firefox throws; `missing ) after argument`

Comment: sorry found it, made a typeo `' };`

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have errors in your script that does not cause any problems when the script is not compressed.

I recommend try using [jslint](http://jslint.org) on the script to verify that it is correct.

Comment: thanks nice tool, what is meant by `Problem at line 88 character 38: Unescaped '-'.

if( to.search( /^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[...`??

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to JSLint is [JavaScriptLint](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php). May be worth checking it in that too. What errors are you getting in the browser? [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox should give you more details of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are using to compress your javascript, but I have noticed from using the [Google Closure compiler](http://closureoptimizer.com/) that it doesn't following the "rules" per se.

Given this code:

```
var t = true;
if (t) { alert("it's true!"); }
```

which gives no errors in JSLint (except for "Implied global: alert 2")

If I compress it using the "who needs whitespace" setting, this is the result

```
var t=true;if(t)alert("it's true!");
```

which is of course optimized, but now gives a JSLint error.

Comment: What i've found is that the compressors didn't add the ';' on the end of the compressed file. I just added one and it now works fine. Thanks all that replied.